# Help with velocity vectors

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a velocity vector that is V(233, 188).

It makes an object moves toward the right-bottom side of the screen in 300 pixels per second when the origin is V(0, 0).

When the position of the object is, for instance, (592, 334), I set the velocity vector to V(294, 55) but the object does not start moving toward that direction... It keeps moving the same direction, but it seems that it makes a small curve of 10 degrees...

What I'm doing is:

```
objectLocation += velocity * elapsedTime;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Verify that the object's location has changed (and that for example 'velocity * elapsedTime' isn't insignificant). Also, you may need to do something to force a re-paint of the object after its location changes.

Comment: no no, what happens is that the location the object starts moving is not the one I set, for example, using the values I provided, it seems that the objects makes a small curve 10 degrees to the right... I forgot to add this info, sorry...

Comment: In that case maybe it's a "rounding error" caused by using integers instead of floating point ... do you know what I mean? You have three things, i.e. 'objectLocation', 'velocity', and 'elapsedTime' ... are these all integers, or floating point, or what? And what programming language are you using?

Comment: Do you still have problems with this?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between (233,188) and (294,55) is not that much, in the grand scheme of things. To verify your code is working, try a vector such as (200,-200). That will cause it to actually bounce off the point in the y-direction.

If that code works, then it's just your values that aren't working.